# Getting connection reset exception when streaming large videos while using WebView and NanoHTTPD

Tags: android, sockets, android-webview, android-mediaplayer, nanohttpd

In my application i have zipped web content. Web content has embedded video in it.

I show the wen content through Android web view. I serve my content through NanoHTTPD Server.
I am on Android 4.2.2 and NanoHTTPD's latest version

My server supports partial content handling through range requests. This error comes in the initial call itself i.e. when accept-range response is sent from my server.

Video as ZipInputInflaterStream is sent in response from my server.

Whenever i try to view a video of large size i get this stack trace.

```
10-03 14:48:28.097: E/NanoHTTPD(9454): java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
10-03 14:48:28.097: E/NanoHTTPD(9454):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:506)
10-03 14:48:28.097: E/NanoHTTPD(9454):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:475)
10-03 14:48:28.097: E/NanoHTTPD(9454):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:507)
10-03 14:48:28.097: E/NanoHTTPD(9454):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
10-03 14:48:28.097: E/NanoHTTPD(9454):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:269)
10-03 14:48:28.097: E/NanoHTTPD(9454):  at test.http.server.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendAsFixedLength(NanoHTTPD.java:806)
10-03 14:48:28.097: E/NanoHTTPD(9454):  at test.http.server.NanoHTTPD$Response.send(NanoHTTPD.java:745)
10-03 14:48:28.097: E/NanoHTTPD(9454):  at test.http.server.NanoHTTPD$HTTPSession.execute(NanoHTTPD.java:1075)
10-03 14:48:28.097: E/NanoHTTPD(9454):  at test.http.server.NanoHTTPD$1$1.run(NanoHTTPD.java:211)
10-03 14:48:28.097: E/NanoHTTPD(9454):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-03 14:48:28.097: E/NanoHTTPD(9454): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: sendto failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
10-03 14:48:28.097: E/NanoHTTPD(9454):  at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
10-03 14:48:28.097: E/NanoHTTPD(9454):  at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:151)
10-03 14:48:28.097: E/NanoHTTPD(9454):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:177)
10-03 14:48:28.097: E/NanoHTTPD(9454):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:473)
10-03 14:48:28.097: E/NanoHTTPD(9454):  ... 8 more
```

It seems the client socket in NanoHTTPD gets disconnected.
Below is the code of NanoHTTPD which throws this error

```
private void sendAsFixedLength(OutputStream outputStream, int pending) throws IOException
    {
        if (requestMethod != Method.HEAD && data != null) {
            int BUFFER_SIZE = 16 * 1024;
            byte[] buff = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            while (pending > 0) {
                int read = data.read(buff, 0, ((pending > BUFFER_SIZE) ? BUFFER_SIZE : pending));
                if (read <= 0) {
                    break;
                }
                outputStream.write(buff, 0, read); //error thrown from here
                pending -= read;
            }
        }
    }
```

outputStream.write throws the above stack trace.

For large file like this after the exception happens the Android media player sends range requests.
This works when i extract the file and send the content through FileInputStream.

Question is NanoHTTPD able to read ZipInputInflaterStream for a larger time ?.Even if it reads why client socket gets closed ?

Please note this problem only happens for large videos like for 19 MB.
For smaller files like 11 MB it works.

cheers,
Saurav

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, after switch to `Release-2.0.5` tag, everything works good.